# How to add a collection inside a firebase document in ReactNative

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

The new syntax for firebase doesn't show how to do this, and the tutorials on the internet are over a year old and don't follow the new firebase syntax.

I have tried the following

```
    const docRef = collection(fireStore, "chats", id);
    const newDocRef = await addDoc(collection(docRef, "messages"), {
      timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      message: userInput,
      displayName: auth.currentUser.email,
      photoURL: auth.currentUser.photoURL,
    })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("New Id: ", newDocRef.id);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log("Meassage creation error: ", e);
      });
```

however I get an error:
FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Invalid collection reference. Collection references must have an odd number of segments, but chats/RXoMunEWYes4mu0HdFHq has 2

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it can be done this way now

```
const newDocRef = await addDoc(collection(fireStore, "chats", id, "messages"), {
      timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
      message: userInput,
      displayName: auth.currentUser.email,
      photoURL: auth.currentUser.photoURL,
    })
```